# How can I not close the connection due to a transaction if I use try-with-resources?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

I have a DAO which has method to insert entities into a MySQL database. That method takes a connection and entity as parameters. In Context.xml file, I set that connection will have `defaultAutoCommit="false"` property, so I don't need to set it inside DAO methods.

```
defaultAutoCommit="false"
```

```
@Override
public boolean insertCarCategory(Connection connection, CarCategory carCategory) {
    int rowNum = 0;
    String query = "INSERT INTO car_category values(?,?,?,?);";
    try (Connection con = connection;
         AutoRollback autoRollback = new AutoRollback(con);
         PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
        statement.setString(1, carCategory.getCarCategory());
        statement.setDouble(2, carCategory.getCostPerOneKilometer());
        statement.setDouble(3, carCategory.getDiscount());
        statement.setBytes(4, ImageUtil.imageToByte(carCategory.getCarCategoryImage()));
        rowNum = statement.executeUpdate();
        //if it used as transaction dont commit and close connection
        autoRollback.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
    return rowNum > 0;
}
```

UserDao method that will be used In Service Layer

```
@Override
public boolean insertUser(Connection connection,User user) {
    int rowNum = 0;
    String query = "INSERT INTO user_info(login,userPassword,userType,userEmail)values(?,?,?,?);";
    ResultSet keys = null;
    try(Connection con = connection;
        AutoRollback autoRollback = new AutoRollback(con);
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        statement.setString(1, user.getLogin());
        statement.setString(2, PasswordUtil.generateStrongPasswordHash(user.getPassword()));
        statement.setString(3, user.getUserType());
        statement.setString(4, user.getUserEmail());
        rowNum = statement.executeUpdate();
        keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (keys.next()) {
            user.setUserId(keys.getInt(1));
        }
        autoRollback.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } finally {
        if (keys != null) {
            try {
                keys.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            }
        }
        }
    return rowNum > 0;
}
```

I use AutoRollBack class that helps me to rollback transaction If commit is false

```
public class AutoRollback implements AutoCloseable  {
    private Connection conn;
    private boolean committed;
    public AutoRollback(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        this.conn = conn;
    }
    public void commit() throws SQLException {
        conn.commit();
        committed = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        if(!committed) {
            conn.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

In the service layer, I use DAO methods. I get a connection from a connection pool and pass it to DAO methods.

```
private void insertCarUser(User user,CarCategory carCategory){
    Connection connection = MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection();
    categoryDao.insertCarCategory(connection,carCategory);
    userDao.insertUser(connection,user);
}
```

How can I not close connection in one of the methods so that it can be used in the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the try-with-resources in the various DAO methods, and instead apply try-with-resource immediately when obtaining a connection:

```java
private void insertCarUser(User user,CarCategory carCategory){
    try (Connection connection = MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection()) {
        categoryDao.insertCarCategory(connection,carCategory);
        userDao.insertUser(connection,user);
    }
}
```

Similarly, you will want to move you transaction handling there, and not in your DAO methods if this operation needs to be atomic.